# Android Repository by Google Broken?

Tags: android, sdk, adk

I am trying to download the android "ADT Plugin for Eclipse" from Google, and I get this error:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Z7VB.png

I have tried disabling my firewall, and forcing (and not forcing) HTTPS.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the problem,

Go to the SDK Manager (Navigate to it on the computer, not from eclipse), then open it up and go to the place where there is a force HTTPS checkbox. I had accidentally pasted the URL to the repository files in the url area up there that was meant for a proxy.

Once I deleted the URL, it worked fine.